# jQuery.removeClass() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website with a slider, and I am trying to make on of the slides clickable.  I have managed to edit the js to wrap the `<div>` in a `<a>`, but that created a new issue.

The way the slider works is that it displays the `<div>` with the class `cameracurrent`.  The slider works fine until it adds `cameracurrent` to my clickable slide.  When the js calls `.removeClass('cameracurrent');`, the class does not get removed.  Thus, the displayed slide is always the same.

Here is some of the code:

```
    var loop;
for (loop=0;loop<amountSlide;loop++)
{
    if (loop == 4) {
        cameraCont.append('<a href=http://www.google.com><div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_'+loop+'" /></a>');
        var div = $('> div:eq('+loop+')',elem);
        target.find('.cameraSlide_'+loop).clone(div);
    } else {
        cameraCont.append('<div class="cameraSlide cameraSlide_'+loop+'" />');
        var div = $('> div:eq('+loop+')',elem);
        target.find('.cameraSlide_'+loop).clone(div);
    }
}
```

...

```
if($(thumbs).length){
                $('li', thumbs).removeClass('cameracurrent');
                $('li', thumbs).eq(slideI).addClass('cameracurrent');
            }
```

The js is 2200+ lines, so I am still trying to wrap my head around it.  But, I believe this is how the `cameracurrent` class is being removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `li` elements while you have only divs with that class...

Comment: @canon http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ - it's the same as `$(thumbs).find("li")`

Comment: `thumbs` is the context that your selector selects against. `$('li')` will look through the entire document. `$('li', thumbs)` will look in whatever thumbs is.

Answer (score 0):

could you try something like this to remove the class?

```
if (thumbs) {
    $(thumbs).find('.cameracurrent').removeClass('cameracurrent');
}
```